# Convert tree nodes to coordinates of endpoints of edges

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, tree

I have a (recombining) binomial tree `t = ((4,), (3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 7))`, where lattice levels are indexed as `(0,1,2,3)`. That is 4 has index 0, while 3, 5 have index 1, and so on. I need a set of the coordinates of endpoints of edges (connecting tree nodes). Naturally, 4 is connected to 3 and 5; 3 is connected to 2 and 4; 5 is connected to 4 and 6.

Any ideas on approach I may take?

The output are elements (in any order) (these are pairs of pairs)

```
[(0,4),(1,3)], [(0,4),(1,5)], 
[(1,3),(2,2)], [(1,3),(2,4)], [(1,5),(2,4)], [(1,5),(2,6)], 
[(2,2),(3,1)], [(2,2),(3,3)], [(2,4),(3,3)], [(2,4),(3,5)], [(2,6),(3,5)], [(2,6),(3,7)]
```

The tree can grow. Any basic data iterable (list, set, tuple, dictionary, etc.) will do.

I thought that converting a tree to a lower diagonal of a matrix would make things easier, but now think may be there is direct approach.

Here is an example of the progression of this recombining tree:
[image]

Kindly let me know, if clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all adjacent nodes are considered pairs:

```
t = ((4,), (3, 5), (2, 4, 6), (1, 3, 5, 7))

from itertools import tee
a, b = tee(t)
next(b)
for ind, (t1, t2) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    print([[(ind, i), (ind + 1, j)] for i in t1 for j in t2])
```

You will have to group the output but this should be closer to what you need:

```
def pairs(t):
    a, b = tee(t)
    next(b)
    for ind, (t1, t2) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
        it = iter(t2)
        nxt = next(it)
        for ele in t1:
            n = next(it)
            yield [(ind, ele), (ind + 1, nxt)]
            yield [(ind, ele), (ind + 1, n)]
            nxt = n


from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(list(pairs(t)),compact=1)
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 4), (1, 3)], [(0, 4), (1, 5)], [(1, 3), (2, 2)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 4)], [(1, 5), (2, 6)], [(2, 2), (3, 1)], [(2, 2), (3, 3)],
 [(2, 4), (3, 3)], [(2, 4), (3, 5)], [(2, 6), (3, 5)], [(2, 6), (3, 7)]]
```

Comment: Great idea... Just not sure why it's adding `[(1, 3), (2, 6)]` (and such) to the output list. These coordinates are not in original list. I'm trying to figure out an improvement.

Comment: Aren't  they coming from  `(3, 5), (2, 4, 6)`?

Comment: Good question. The tree is (recombining) binomial. So, each node connects to only two nodes. Thus, 3 connects to 2, 4; 5 connects to 4, 6 and so on. The exampled output underlines this idea. Just like any other binomial tree, there are n nodes at step n; the tree grows linearly (but number of paths doesn't :) ). I added a picture for the visual.

Comment: Ah yep indeed, the binomial tree should have been a good clue ;) Does the order matter as in could http://pastebin.com/Ydjn9b8v work ?

Comment: In output example: tuple elements are ordered, but list elements are not. So, `[(0,4),(1,3)]=[(1,3),(0,4)]`, but not `[(4,0),(3,1)]`. Tuples contain coordinates as in `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]`; lists indicate the endpoints of edges connecting the nodes. So, flipping x and y coordinates would not work (unless ALL coordinates are flipped making the tree grow vertically, instead of horizontally, :) ). thanks for your looking into this and helping me think this through as well :)

Comment: No prob, can you explain why it is `[(1,3),(2,2)], [(1,3),(2,4)], [(1,5),(2,2)], [(1,5),(2,6)]` and not `[(1,3),(2,2)], [(1,3),(2,4)], [(1,5),(2,4)], [(1,5),(2,6)]`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Yes, instead of `[(1,5), (2,2)]` there should be `[(1,5), (2,4)]`, which is an edge in the diagram. Apologies for the confusion. The question is updated.

Comment: The second part to the answer should do what you want then, if you really need the output grouped you can change the logic

Comment: Thx Padraic. Works well; and, I've learned a few new things (`tee`, `yield`,...) :)